# How do you insert MPEG-2 movie into PowerPoint 2010 presentation?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, avi, microsoft-powerpoint-2010, mpeg, mpeg2

I am trying to insert an `MPEG-2` movie into my PowerPoint 2010 presentation. It plays fine in the Windows Media Player on this computer, and the equivalent `AVI` movie inserts no problem, but the MPEG-2 shows up with haphazard green squares instead of the correct picture, although during playback the correct melody sounds.

I prefer `MPEG-2` to `AVI` since it takes 16 Mb instead of 600 Mb...
Thank you very much.

Comment: Try http://www.headbands.com/gspot/ to check the codecs

Comment: @edelwater Thank you, tried it - all required codecs are installed. This is not surprising, after all -- the MPEG video did play fine in the Windows Media Player, without codecs, this would have been impossible...

Answer (score 0):

Used Microsoft Expression Encoder 4, available for free download by Microsoft, to encode `MPEG-2` to a `WMV` format, which I was able to insert into a PowerPoint presentation without any problems.